# how to set default update_user_meta values wordpress

Tags: users, user-meta

so i installed a theme which gives a default value to a meta

the code the theme uses is

```
      update_user_meta($uid, '_sb_pkg_type', 'free');
```

i would like to add this code to wordpress core so whenever a user registers it sets a default value of 'free' to _sb_pkg_type instead of nothing..

meaning i would like to know how can i set a default user meta to _sb_pkg_type in WordPress core

sorry if this question is not understood as my English is not my first languge.

Comment: You shouldn't be modifying WordPress core. You would need to create a plugin that just does the same thing that the theme does.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `user_register` action to run your user meta update when a user registers.

```
/**
 * Sets the user meta key '_sb_pkg_type' to 'free' when a user registers.
 *
 * @param int $user_id ID for the user who has registered.
 */
function wpse_update_user_meta_pkg_type( $user_id ) {
    update_user_meta( $user_id, '_sb_pkg_type', 'free' );
}
// Fire late to try to ensure this is done after any other function hooked to `user_register`.
add_action( 'user_register','wpse_update_user_meta_pkg_type', PHP_INT_MAX, 1 );
```

The code above uses the priority `PHP_INT_MAX` to try and ensure that it's the last thing triggered on the `user_register` hook, but without knowing how the plugin you're working with is handling the user meta, it's hard to say if this will be sufficient.

I did verify that this code updates the user meta key `_sb_pkg_type` with a value of `free` when a new user is registered though.